# Geometery - Cross Section

Tags: geometry

I have a flat topped pyramid I'm trying to calculate a 45 degree cross section of.  I know the dimensions at the pyramids top and bottom, I know the distance to the centre point of the cross section and I know the angle of the cross section.  Can somebody help me with the maths to calcualte the dimensions of the resulting trapezoid the cross section creates.

I have included a diagram as an example of what I'm trying to calculate with known dimensions.

Example Diagram:

[image: img]

Comment: I believe you also need the distance between the top and the bottom of the "pyramid". Also, does the line formed by intersection of the cross-section plane with the plane at the bottom parallel to the longer edge at the bottom?

Comment: Hi Futurologist, I do have the distance between the top and bottom, in this example it was 1000.  I'm not sure I understand your other question, can you explain what you mean and I'll answer.

Comment: The cross-section plane, when extended intersects the (extended) horizontal plane at the bottom. The intersection is a line. Is this intersection line parallel to the longer edge of the bottom rectangle?

Comment: I am asking to be sure that the cross-section does not cut the pyramid in some non-trapezoidal general quadrilateral, but always in a nice symmetric (isosceles) trapezoid, with two parallel sides.

Comment: OK thanks for clarity, glad you asked as I've realised what I'm asking for is more challenging that originally requested. Based of the pyramid is 1778 x 1000, top is 178,100.  However, the two do not have to be centred, for example the bases long edge could be level with the top long edge so you have more of a 3D triangle with wedge end.  The cross section however is measured 500mm down from the top but on the angle, i.e. centre point of top to centre of bottom and total depth is 4000mm.  Therefore, the sides of the cross sectional plane are not parrellell in most cases i'd need to calc.

Comment: Trying to calculate the properties of the red area; https://screenrec.com/share/pRlCU9W0G6  What i'm trying to do is plot it on a chart so i essentially want to define it's corner x,y values relative to 0,0 being it's centre point

Comment: That is not enough information. If the relative position of the top and bottom is arbitrary (even if their pairs of respective edges are parallel) you need to describe somehow their relative position. For example, where is the orthogonal projection of the center of the top relative to the center of the bottom. Ant not just the distance between the two, but the location of the projection of the top's center inside the bottom square.

Comment: You need to provide the necessary and sufficient number of parameters that determine the exact shape of the pyramid. Then, you need to provide the position and orientation of the cross-section.

Comment: how is this related to programming ? How is your input stored (mesh,dimensions,...) what ewxactly is expected output (dimensions,polyline ?) show code if there is any. Where exactly are you stuck? plane equation, intersection between plane and quadrilateral or triangle?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not about programming but math ...